# statistical metrics for KNN model with different K value of iris model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, data-science

I wrote some python codes to fit the famous iris dataset with KNN model, I tried with different k value, as k=2, k=3, k=5, to my understanding with these different k values, the confusion matrix, accuracy score and classification report value should be different, however, whatever k value I give, the statistical metrics output are all the same, also, the "precision", "recall", and "f1-score" are all 1.00, as in the snapshot [codes and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PTRD.png). Did I miss something here? Thanks!

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# first split the dataset into its attributes and labels
X = data.iloc[:, :-1].values  
y = data.iloc[:, 4].values 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, 
random_state=42)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

# Instantiate learning model (k = 5)
clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
# Fitting the model
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print(y_pred)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score 

print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("classification report:---------------------------\n")
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, labels=iris.target))
```

Comment: Where did you load your data from? External CSV or `sklearn's` built-in iris dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you've made a mistake while loading and the dataset and splitting them into `X` and `y`. Checkout this correction. It gives out proper results. However, the `iris` dataset is very simple without much [multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity) or [heteroscedasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity). This means `knn` won't have much trouble in classifying them perfectly and you won't see much difference in output metrics via changing the `knn` parameters. To observe drastic changes, you should pick data with higher difficulties.

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()

# import some data to play with
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
y = iris.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, 
random_state=42)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

# Instantiate learning model (k = 5)
clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10)
# Fitting the model
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print(y_pred)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score 

print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("classification report:---------------------------\n")
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, labels=iris.target))
```

This shows

```py
[1 0 2 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 2 1 1 1 2 0 1 0 2 2 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 1 2
 0 0 0 1 2 2 0 0]
[[19  0  0]
 [ 0  8  5]
 [ 0  6  7]]
0.7555555555555555
classification report:---------------------------
...
```

The accuracy does change when you tune the `knn` parameters.

Comment: Thanks, tried to only take the first two features and give to X with you modification, then got: k=2, accuracy_score=0.833; k=3, accuracy_score=0.833; k=5, accuracy_score=0.8267. What you said is correct!

Answer (score 1):

I think your output is correct: you are getting perfect classification for your test set regardless of the value you choose for k. The iris data set is relatively easy. There is only real overlap between the versicolor and virginica species, and then only for a select few specimens (maybe 5-6 or so). Check out [this website](https://rpubs.com/Tonnia/irisknn) for some plots that show this. Since you are only testing 30% of the data, it is likely that these few specimens are not in your test set. You should see some variation based on k if you run the prediction for the entire data set.

Try changing these lines to see it:

```
y_pred = clf.predict(X)
print(confusion_matrix(y, y_pred))
```

Comment: Thanks, after input entire dataseet, got: k=2, accuracy_score=0.973;k=3, accuracy_score=0.96; k=5, accuracy_score=0.9667; what you said is correct!